# php code improvement refactor

Tags: php, refactoring

Hi staskoverflow community.

How can i improve next structure of PHP 5 code.
A list of models $months (more than 12) 
$month->days (more than 31)

$day->clients a list of clients
$day->someActions a list of actions for $clients

i need to invoke every $action for every $client. So my construction is:

```
<?php
foreach($monthes as $month) {
    foreach($month->days as $day) {
        foreach($day->clients as $client) {
            foreach($day->actions as $action) {
                $action->run($client);
            }
        }
    }
} ?>
```

So there are four foreach loops, can i improve this code ?

Comment: I don't think you can improve the performance or readability of this specific block of code. Perhaps if you could explain what these $actions are, or what this application does, we might be able to help. For example, are your `days` and `clients` properties lazily filled from a database? In that case, this code could get very very slow with lots of clients and months. In a nutshell, I'm saying: Needs more context please.

Comment: You might also be interested in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to move out of nested loops?
the code you have is very clear to understand and if your objective is to optimize the performance of this method, then the approach I would go with would be:

1. I will first try to reduce the number of iterations. you can do this by asking questions to yourself like how many months data do I actually want to display on the go?
2. Similar questions can be asked about days and clients
3. do you have a break condition? What i mean by this is,

   $result =  $action->run($client);
   if("break_condition" == $result){
   break;
   }

this should considerably reduce the number of iterations.